# How to bypass the same origin policy to execute framekiller script on a different domain

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, clickjacking, framebusting

I created a framekiller script in such way it allows framing a page only in selected domain to prevent clickjacking. 
Framekiller Code:

```
    <style id="antiClickjack">
      body {
           display: none !important;
           }
   </style>

   <script>
    if (top.length > 0)
    {
        if (self.location == top.location) {
            alert("same");
            var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
            antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
        }
        else if (self.location.hostname == top.location.hostname || self.location.hostname.toString() == "www.TrustedSite1.com" || self.location.hostname.toString() == "www.TrustedSite2.com") 
        {  
            var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
            antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
        }
        else 
        {
            top.location.replace(self.location);
        }
    }
    else 
    {            
        var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
        antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
    }

</script>
```

But latest browser Follow **SAME ORIGIN POLICY** so it's not allowing executes framekiller script in Other Websites (trusted websites)

My question is "How to bypass the same origin policy to execute framekiller script on a different domain"

Thank You.